# sqldataadapter multiple tables and transaction

Tags: c#, ado.net, rollback, dataadapter, sqldataadapter

[ADO.NET - Updating Multiple DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889102/ado-net-updating-multiple-datatables)

I found the question above which is exactly what I am looking for and trying to implement a solution...

I am trying to see a best solution to updating multiple table into sqlserver 2008 and ensure transaction on the multiple tables.  If inserting into one table fails, rollback the previous updates on other tables.

1. sqldataadapter only updates one table at a time
2. I know we can do transaction on one dataadapter at a time but need to update multiple tables

Below are codes modified from the answer provided above, but it error out with the dataadapter.  I think I need to set the insert, update and delete commands but not sure how that works if there are multple tables??? can someone fill in the missing link?

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlServerConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            //table is an array of datatable and contains data to be inserted
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables.Add(table[i]);
            }

            SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();

            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            //Need to set insert,select, update, delete???? on multiple tables?

            //dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = trans; //null object error here
            dataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = trans;
            dataAdapter.DeleteCommand.Transaction = trans;

            try
            {

                dataAdapter.Update(ds);
                trans.Commit();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                trans.Rollback();

            }
```

Comment: Read the 2nd comment from that answer.

Comment: I have read it many times before I posted; unfortunately I am still confuse.  But looking for a best practices of implementing this...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's input.  I think previous answered by @Charlie with this q/a threw me off:[ADO.NET - Updating Multiple DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889102/ado-net-updating-multiple-datatables)

I thought maybe you can use a dataset for the updates, but I guess you still have to create additional data adapter, and then call update.  So the answer to the previous question then is the only other simplify way to do what @gamzu07 wanted to do is use an array rather than declaring it each time.  The below code works but seem retarded to me, does anyone have any better idea other than maybe building the insert commands and executing that....?

```
            SqlDataAdapter[] dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter[table.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; i++)
            {

                dataAdapter[i] = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from " + table[i].TableName, con);
                SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter[i]);
                dataAdapter[i].InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
                dataAdapter[i].Fill(table[i]);

            }

            SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                for(int i=0;i < table.Length;i++){
                    dataAdapter[i].InsertCommand.Transaction = trans;
                    dataAdapter[i].Update(table[i]);
                }
                trans.Commit();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                trans.Rollback();
            }
```

Comment: I use wirble's solution myself, too. However, note that DataAdapter.Update() will execute sqlcommand for each single DataRow and modify their status, but when your transaction rolls back, those modified DataRowStates will out of date. So you should be careful to use this solution when you access DataRowState property in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to define commands for each of those - I suggest using [SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz.aspx) for the job.

Note, however, that SqlDataAdapter only works on **one** DataTable. Not clear from the documentation if that is the first table:

> The Update method retrieves rows from the table listed in the first mapping before performing an update.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx

...Or maybe just the only table in the DataSet that is named Table:

> Update |  Calls the respective INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements for each inserted, updated, or deleted row in the specified DataSet from a DataTable named "Table."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx

In any case, your loop over the tables is going to need to call Update, if you're using an SqlDataAdapter.

**EDIT**

In any case, the SqlDataAdapter is not a good choice here, as far as I can tell. If all you're trying to do is share a transaction between DataTables, just use a series of SqlCommands that share an SqlTransaction.

(if this is not clear enough, I'll add a code sample when I get to work)

Comment: I understand that data adapter works for one table, but from the previous question and answer; it seems as if we can use one Dataset with multiple tables to do the transaction update.  Maybe this is not the case.  I know how to loop over each dataadapter and add the table, then call update.  But I want to update multiple tables within a transaction? Is the best practices then is to use SqlCommandBuilder for transaction updates of multiple tables?  There is no way to do this for Sqldataadapter and data set?