# Insert record from c# datatable to a database

Tags: c#, database, list, datatable

I have this datatable, actually a list of datatable
`List<DataTable> lstDataSource`, now for each table in the list I know there are exactly 6 rows, (monday to saturday!), but there can be any number of columns (well from 6 to 14 that is, the number of hours an employee is working per day!)
So I know the limits of both rows and columns in each datatable. My point is how do I use this list of datatable to update (rather insert) all these values in read database table `EmpWorkSchedule`.
What I know is total rows inserted would be `lstDataSource.Count * 6` right? Also, for any column that doesn't have values, (some employee work 6 hrs, some 7 hrs etc... ) other columns in that rows would be just set to null. (They are defined as nullable in database). I hope I madeself clear. So, how can I do this?
Also, if there's anything unclear, please feel free to ask.

**EDIT :** I have this list of `DataTable`  `List<DataTable> lstDataTable`, what I want is to insert all rows from each of these tables in the list, to a database table named `EmpWorkSchedule`, all the values in each row are sequential, that is first column corresponds to column 1 in database table, and so on, okay? But now all rows have values for all column, some have 6, some 7, some 8.. What I want is that for the columns, for which, there is no value in the datarow, should be left null in the database table, rest all values should be inserted.

Also, using an adapted doesn't seems likely because its used with select, I am not selecting anything, I am inserting something.

Comment: Am afraid your question is not clear enough

Comment: So what's the problem, what have you tried? Have you tried to use a DataAdapter and provide appropriate Insert- and UpdateCommands? What dbms are you using? Can you show the sql to insert a record?

Comment: @TimSchmelter
I could try a datadapted, but issn't that used with SELECT only? I have to insert all this data to the table, not select anything

Comment: @JohnGathogo
Is it clear now???

Comment: @Razort4x A dataAdapter will also do Insert, Update, and Delete. You just need to tell it what SQL to execute for each of those scenarios.

Comment: Monday(1), Tuesday(2), Wednesday(3), Thursday(4), Friday(5)...  5 != 6 IMHO  =)

Comment: @C.Barlow
sorry, I meant saturday :-(, updated now :-)

Comment: why haven't you used a DataSet instead ?

Comment: @HichemC
I can use that if that would be useful rather than datatable, but I seriously have no idea how would I do that with dataset too.. :-(
Cause I need to insert, not update or select

Comment: dealing with a dataset holding all you datables inside would help a lot if you want to have DataAdapter do the inserts for you

Comment: @HichemC
Thanks a lot, but it would really help if you provide an example :-(

Comment: @Razort4x here are some useful exemples : [exemple1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889102/ado-net-updating-multiple-datatables) and [exemple2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y(v=vs.71).aspx) hope it would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just need to Loop on your DataTable and save each row records on your DB
Something Like:

Your DataTable

```
Col1 |  Col2
abc  |  456 
def  |  789
```

On Your Code Behind do something like:

```
foreach(DataRow row in YourDataTable.Rows)
{

  string myColumn1  = row["Col1"].ToString();  
  int mycolumn2 =  Convert.ToInt32(row["Col2"]);

  //Your Insert Statement
  //First Loop you will get  
  //myColumn1 = abc and myColumn2=456
  //2nd loop will be def and 789

}
```

Regards