# How does SQLDataAdapter.Update check if DB Keys were violated?

Tags: c#, ado.net, .net-3.5, dataset, sqldataadapter

Trying to add an entity to the database which requires several tables to be updates (master entity table, relationship table, status table, ect) and if one of these 4 table updates fail I need to roll back the others.  The legacy code I'm working with decided to use `SQLDataAdapters` so I decided to use the transaction feature of these and roughly followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5889234/643619) (but with 4 datasets instead of one)

The first dataset update in the transaction occurs with no exceptions, but when it gets to second it says it violates the key for the first not existing.  Why would the key be violated when the first update appears to have gone through?  Below is a rough approximation of what I'm doing.  Thanks!

```
public bool CreateEntity(Dataset ds1, Dataset ds2, Dataset ds3, Dataset ds4)
{
    conn.Open();
    var trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
    dataAdapter1.UpdateCommand.Transaction = trans;
    dataAdapter1.InsertCommand.Transaction = trans;
    dataAdapter1.DeleteCommand.Transaction = trans;

    dataAdapter2.UpdateCommand.Transaction = trans;
    dataAdapter2.InsertCommand.Transaction = trans;
    dataAdapter2.DeleteCommand.Transaction = trans;

    dataAdapter3.UpdateCommand.Transaction = trans;
    dataAdapter3.InsertCommand.Transaction = trans;
    dataAdapter3.DeleteCommand.Transaction = trans;

    dataAdapter4.UpdateCommand.Transaction = trans;
    dataAdapter4.InsertCommand.Transaction = trans;
    dataAdapter4.DeleteCommand.Transaction = trans;

    try
    {
        dataAdapter1.Update(ds1); // Succeeds
        dataAdapter2.Update(ds2); // Exception occurs here
        dataAdapter3.Update(ds3);
        dataAdapter4.Update(ds4);
        trans.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        trans.Rollback();
        conn.Close();
        return false;
    }

    conn.Close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Without knowing the contents of the datasets it's impossible to say. But the SQLDataAdaptor does no checking itself: any errors are coming from the database server. As a guess, is it possible that ds2 has a relation to the data in ds1, a new row is being added in ds1 with an IDENTITY PK which is zero in ds2?

Comment: @simonatrcl Well when I mouse over ds1 in debug the row ds2 depends on is indeed there; the key that's being violated when attempting to update ds2 is the "Is identity PK in ds1" key which I theoretically just added since the ds1 update went fine.  Sort of makes me think that when the ds2 update happens its checking the key violations against the live db instead of the one held in transation?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is. The insert in ds1 assigns the ID and it gets passed back to the ds1 member. However, the ds2 element still has zero and the FK up-date fails as there is no matching 0 pk in the ds1 table.

You need to check ds1 for any inserts after the Update and get out newly assigned id's; then put them in the appropriate ds2 elements and the update ds2. All a bit long winded.

If you have the time you'd be better off using something like Entity Framework where DataAdaptors are not used (not directly) and the EF Model takes care of all that stuff for you.

Comment: Well, when I am creating the rows for each dataset to insert, I assign the correct new ID to the row in ds2 (from looking it up in ds1 after the insert there)... but I suppose that wouldn't matter if ds2 is still looking at live DB (which has nothing since transaction hasn't committed)?

Comment: It should be OK since they are in the same transaction, and thus can see any changes made by that transaction - that's part of the point: in a transaction only other stuff in the same transaction can see it so partly written data can't be seen OUTSIDE the transaction. So if you're doing that, you should be OK...If this is SQL Server, I'd hook up the Profiler and check the individual updates/inserts to see what's happening.

Comment: Ok Ill try that.  Yeah that's why I was confused... I create row for ds1, add to ds1, get key for newly added row, then create ds2 row using found key, add to ds2 (repeat for ds3 & ds4) and then I finally run the above code.  So all the datasets should have all the info they need. (And yes it is SQL Server)

Comment: That sounds fine, but the key only gets generated at the insert - just to be clear - if it's an identity.

Comment: Right, before I call the above function I do all the ds1.AddRow stuff, and it does generate the key (because I am able to find it via other columns).

Comment: OK. Can you add the table definition, the class definition and code to add the row and get the generated id and apply it to the other objects? It sounds odd. I'd still try to use the profiler to get the last statement prior to the error to give me a clue exactly which row is failing so I could investigate it.

Comment: Sure, here's the relevant stuff [ http://kopy.io/ZcJG0 ] (had to sanitize it sorry work for the state).  The adapters themselves simply just DataMap to the relevant tables and then set up their various Select/Insert/Delete Commands.  If something doesn't make sense just ask I probably messed it up when sanitizing the names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74938/discussion-between-hershizer33-and-simon-at-rcl).

Comment: OK. I'm going to be here until 18:20 (it's 17:30 now). But I think I see a possible problem.

Comment: Left a comment at the chat link, but I'm pretty sure that the column is an IDENTITY column in the db and that will always be assigned by the db. I'm on UK time and I'll be here mid-morning monday (and occasionally over the weekend possibly) if you want to discuss. Cheers -