# Use DataTable Update() Method to Update Multiple SQL Tables?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataadapter, sqldataadapter

I'm trying to update my SQL backend with data that has changed in my webform.

That data is initially fetched from SQL like so

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("my.storedprocedure", cs);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customerID", custid));

command.CommandTimeout = 300;

connection.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
connection.Close();

sda.FillSchema(myDataTable, SchemaType.Source);

sda.Fill(myDataTable);
```

The stored procedure makes a selection

```
SELECT c.*
,cs.*
,p.*
,sl.*
,drl.*
FROM tableC as c
INNER JOIN tableCS as cs ON c.[custID] = cs.[custID]
INNER JOIN tableSL as sl ON cs.[custStatusID] = sl.[custStatusID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableP as p ON c.custID = p.custID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableDRL as drl ON cs.custID = drl.custID
WHERE c.[custID] = @custID AND c.[EndDate] IS NULL AND cs.[EndDate] IS NULL
```

I then manipulate the data table that is filled with this stored procedure, call a `dt.NewRow()`, add values to that new row, add the row into the data table. Set fields in the previous row, etc.

**My question is, when I get ready to call a `SqlDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)` will the data adapter go ahead and make the update to all the tables I joined too? Based on what's in my data table?**

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no - a single adapter is for a single table. You need to use a DataSet if you are using ADO.NET.

Using a DataSet:

[Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ADO.NET - Updating Multiple DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889102/ado-net-updating-multiple-datatables)

[Fill DataSet with multiple Tables and update them with DataAdapter](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2004/08/22/Fill-DataSet-with-multiple-Tables-and-update-them-with-DataAdapter)

Using TableAdapterManager:

[TableAdapterManager Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384426.aspx)